How to extract a list of URLs from JSON using jq
Microsoft Clarity returns JSON. I am able to extract the following portion of JSON using JQ:
$ echo $JSON | jq '.[] | select(.metricName == "PopularPages") | .[]'
"PopularPages"
[
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2023/09/14/boost.html",
    "visitsCount": "8"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/02/11/javascript-named-arguments.html",
    "visitsCount": "8"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2023/08/20/pytest.html",
    "visitsCount": "7"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2022/01/10/wsl-backup.html",
    "visitsCount": "7"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/av_studio/640-music21.html",
    "visitsCount": "5"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/llm/4000-wsl.html",
    "visitsCount": "4"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/04/28/buildah-podman.html",
    "visitsCount": "4"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2020/10/27/installing-a-new-ssh-key-on-awc-ec2-with-user-data.html",
    "visitsCount": "3"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/av_studio/570-ableton-push-standalone.html",
    "visitsCount": "3"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/git/600-partial-clone.html",
    "visitsCount": "3"
  }
]

However, I cannot figure out how to reduce the above JSON to a list of url values, one per line, like this:
https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2023/09/14/boost.html
https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/02/11/javascript-named-arguments.html
https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2023/08/20/pytest.html
https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2022/01/10/wsl-backup.html
https://www.mslinn.com/av_studio/640-music21.html
https://www.mslinn.com/llm/4000-wsl.html
https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/04/28/buildah-podman.html
https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2020/10/27/installing-a-new-ssh-key-on-awc-ec2-with-user-data.html
https://www.mslinn.com/av_studio/570-ableton-push-standalone.html
https://www.mslinn.com/git/600-partial-clone.html

What incantation might yield the desired result?
The JSON comes back in a structure like this:
[
    ...
    {
        "metricName": "PopularPages",
        "information": [
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2023/09/14/boost.html",
                "visitsCount": "8"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/02/11/javascript-named-arguments.html",
                "visitsCount": "8"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2023/08/20/pytest.html",
                "visitsCount": "7"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2022/01/10/wsl-backup.html",
                "visitsCount": "7"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/av_studio/640-music21.html",
                "visitsCount": "5"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/llm/4000-wsl.html",
                "visitsCount": "4"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/04/28/buildah-podman.html",
                "visitsCount": "4"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2020/10/27/installing-a-new-ssh-key-on-awc-ec2-with-user-data.html",
                "visitsCount": "3"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/av_studio/570-ableton-push-standalone.html",
                "visitsCount": "3"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.mslinn.com/git/600-partial-clone.html",
                "visitsCount": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]


https://jqplay.org/

it would really help to have a sample of the input, too

You have selected the object with this part.
.[] | select(.metricName == "PopularPages")

Now you need to drill down to the urls on that object
.[] | select(.metricName == "PopularPages").information[].url


That works, now we just need to add -r to remove quotes

To extract the list of URLs from the JSON data using jq, you can use the following command:
echo $JSON | jq -r '.[] | select(.metricName == "PopularPages") | .[].url'

Explanation:

-r: This flag outputs raw strings instead of JSON-encoded strings.
.[]: This selects each item in the array at the root level of your JSON.
select(.metricName == "PopularPages"): This filters out the objects where the metricName is "PopularPages".
.[]: This accesses the array of objects inside the "PopularPages" metric.
.url: This extracts the url field from each object in the array.

This command will return each URL on a new line, which matches the desired output format.
If your JSON is stored in a file rather than a variable, you can replace echo $JSON | with jq -r '...' yourfile.json.

This is obviously ChatGPT generated content.

No idea about that, but it gives this error: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '|' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
.[] | select(.metricName == "PopularPages") | | .[]
jq: 1 compile error

A flag will do. I said it there and I'll say it here: This answer reeks of AI generated response, considering the timeline and formatting. I would even say, given the context of the question (or lack thereof), is even incorrect.

I agree @JeffMercado but my flag was denied for insufficient evidence, so a warning seems usefull since this won't be deleted
